# Adding player to database through JFrame gives nullpointer - cannot find why

Tags: java, mysql, sql, nullpointerexception

First time posting a question here. Mainly because after endless searching I still haven't been able to find the solution, which I wouldn't be surprised about to be a really easy one I am simply overlooking.

(note: names of variables and such are in mainly in Dutch since that is my language, shouldn't matter much though.)

I have been working on a project in which I linked a JFrame to a database and for as far as adding players (see later) to the database goes it perfectly works. Where my issue resides is in refreshing the JFrame that shows the players currently in the database. With my current code, no matter what I try, it returns me a nullpointer exception. To save a giant bulk of text I have put the exact exception in a [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/zCvtAr05/).

Onto the code I have in the JFrame that adds the player (I'm leaving out the by NetBeans automatically generated code for  now)

```
public class InschrijvenSpeler extends javax.swing.JFrame {

private InschrijvenSpeler inschrijvenSpeler;
private SpelerFrame spelerFrame;

public InschrijvenSpeler() {
    initComponents();
    setVisible(true);
    this.spelerFrame = spelerFrame;
    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(InschrijvenSpeler.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
}

private void btnToevoegenActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                             
    String Voornaam = this.txtVnaam.getText();
    String Achternaam = this.txtAnaam.getText();
    String Straat = this.txtStr.getText();
    String Huisnummer = this.txtHnr.getText();
    String Postcode = this.txtPcode.getText();
    String woonplaats = this.txtWplaats.getText();
    String Telefoonnummer = this.txtTelNr.getText();
    String Email = this.txtEmail.getText();

    try {
        Connection conn = DataBaseConnector.getConnection();
        Statement stat = conn.createStatement();

        String prepStatInsertSpeler = "INSERT INTO speler (speler_id, voornaam, achternaam, straat, huisnummer, postcode, woonplaats, telefoonnummer, email) "
                + "VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
        PreparedStatement prepStat = conn.prepareStatement(prepStatInsertSpeler);

        spelerID spelerID = new spelerID();
        spelerID.getIdVerhoging();

        prepStat.setString(1, spelerID.getReportVandaag() + spelerID.converteerId());
        prepStat.setString(2, Voornaam);
        prepStat.setString(3, Achternaam);
        prepStat.setString(4, Straat);
        prepStat.setString(5, Huisnummer);
        prepStat.setString(6, Postcode);
        prepStat.setString(7, woonplaats);
        prepStat.setString(8, Telefoonnummer);
        prepStat.setString(9, Email);

        prepStat.executeUpdate();

    } catch (SQLException exc) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Speler niet opgeslagen in de database" + exc.toString());
    }

    this.setVisible(false);
    spelerFrame.dispose();
    this.spelerFrame.vulSpelerTabel();
    spelerFrame.setVisible(true);
```

---

Since I am calling a method in my other JFrame here (the method called vulSpelerTabel, translated "fillPlayerTable"), here is the code of that method:

---

```
public class SpelerFrame extends javax.swing.JFrame {

private ArrayList<Speler> spelers;

public SpelerFrame() {
    initComponents();
    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(SpelerFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
    spelers = new ArrayList();
    vulSpelerTabel();
}

public void vulSpelerTabel() {

    spelers.clear();

    //Definieren van de header kolommen.
    String[] kolommen = {"speler_id", "voornaam", "achternaam", "straat",
        "huisnummer", "postcode", "woonplaats",
        "telefoonnummer", "email", "rating", "aantal_geen_betalingen", "gewonnen_inleggeld"};

    DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(kolommen, 0);

    //Clearing the table.
    DefaultTableModel clearModel = (DefaultTableModel) tblSpelers.getModel();
    clearModel.setRowCount(0);

    //Spelers ophalen uit database
    try {
        Connection conn = DataBaseConnector.getConnection();
        String selectSpelers = "SELECT * FROM speler";
        Statement statement = conn.createStatement();
        ResultSet result = statement.executeQuery(selectSpelers);

        //Resultaat doorlopen.
        while (result.next()) {
            String speler_id = result.getString("speler_id");
            String voornaam = result.getString("voornaam");
            String achternaam = result.getString("achternaam");
            String straat = result.getString("straat");
            String huisnummer = result.getString("huisnummer");
            String postcode = result.getString("postcode");
            String woonplaats = result.getString("woonplaats");
            String telefoonnummer = result.getString("telefoonnummer");
            String email = result.getString("email");
            double rating = result.getDouble("rating");
            int betalingen = result.getInt("aantal_geen_betalingen");
            double gewonnen_inleggeld = result.getDouble("gewonnen_inleggeld");

            Speler speler = new Speler(speler_id, voornaam, achternaam,
                    straat, huisnummer, postcode,
                    woonplaats, telefoonnummer, email, rating, betalingen,
                    gewonnen_inleggeld);
            spelers.add(speler);
        }
    } catch (SQLException exc) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Fout bij het ophalen van de "
                + "spelers uit de database"
                + exc.toString());
    }

    for (Speler speler : spelers) {
        model.addRow(speler.getInfo());;
    }

    //model koppelen aan JTable
    this.tblSpelers.setModel(model);
}
```

---

Lastly here is the SQL table that the data is being put into:

---

```
CREATE TABLE `speler` (
`speler_id` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
`voornaam` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
`achternaam` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
`straat` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
`huisnummer` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
`postcode` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
`woonplaats` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
`telefoonnummer` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
`email` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
`rating` double NOT NULL DEFAULT '1000',
`aantal_geen_betalingen` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
`gewonnen_inleggeld` double DEFAULT '0',
PRIMARY KEY (`speler_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

I hope I didn't forget anything, and moreover that someone can see that one mistake I must have made somewhere which is giving me the nullpointer exception that I am getting. A few things to note:

- The player DOES get added to the database, but does NOT show up on the JFrame that shows all players (named "SpelerFrame.java") (Since the frame doesn't refresh).
- The nullpointer exception shows up when pressing the "toevoegen" (translated: Add) button. Since the above note is the case I would assume it happens in the last few lines of the code of this button ("btnToevoegen").
- Though the SQL database has more than 9 values to fill in, the others all have defaults. The "speler_id" is determined elsewhere, but I am 100% certain that is not the issue, since the issue still shows up when completely commenting out the lines of "speler_id" and giving it a default value in SQL.

Edit: Since apparently the pastebin was overlooked, here is the NPE that gets thrown:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException

at Views.InschrijvenSpeler.btnToevoegenActionPerformed(InschrijvenSpeler.java:194)

at Views.InschrijvenSpeler.access$200(InschrijvenSpeler.java:11)

at Views.InschrijvenSpeler$3.actionPerformed(InschrijvenSpeler.java:115)

at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)

at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2346)

at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)

at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)

at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)

at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6525)

at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3321)

at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6290)

at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2234)

at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4881)

at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2292)

at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4703)

at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4898)

at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4533)

at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4462)

at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2278)

at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2739)

at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4703)

at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:746)

at java.awt.EventQueue.access$400(EventQueue.java:97)

at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:697)

at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:691)

at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)

at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)

at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)

at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:719)

at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:717)

at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)

at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)

at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:716)

at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)

at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)

at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)

at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)

at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)

at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

Comment: Where in your code does the NPE get thrown ?

Comment: add exception to your question

Comment: The exception is in the pastebin. It gets thrown upon pressing the add button as explained in the 2nd note at the bottom of my question.

Comment: At which line? please add the stacktrace. do remember, you are alread leaving out code, which influences the stacktrace results (for us to read)

Comment: @Stultuske er.. what exactly is the stacktrace >_<? Really new to this :\ Anyway, I added the exception if that helps.

Edit: the only thing I'm really leaving out for as far as I am aware is the "generated code"  bit, since this part cannot be edited in NetBeans anyway I wouldn't see much of a problem here.

Comment: Which line is 194th line of `InschrijvenSpeler.java`?

Comment: @Tom 194 is "spelerFrame.dispose();" That along with 195 and 196 are the lines with which I was attempting to refresh the SpelerFrame.java, but failing at doing so (I tried a multitude of methods by the way)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
this.spelerFrame = spelerFrame;
```

This is a call to itself. Since you are not passing a frame through the constructor it will always remain null and thus result in a NPE

You could try the following code

```
this.spelerFrame = new SpelerFrame();
```

I doubt that this is your intended behaviour though. I suggest you read up about adding frames to your main window/frame.

**EDIT:**

To solve this particular problem, the constructor of `InschrijvenSpeler` should be changed to `public InschrijvenSpeler(SpelerFrame spelerFrame) {` and it should be accessed like `new InschrijvenSpeler(this).setVisible(true);`

Comment: Well, yes and no I think. It would be the solution, if I then dispose the old "SpelerFrame.java" window. Gotta look into that.

Comment: Or rather, instead of disposing the old frame, pass it as an argument to the constructor of `InschrijvenSpeler` so you can re-use it in that class

Comment: Having a slight burnout here on java code :\ Care to elaborate?

Comment: Currently you are using an empty constructor `public InschrijvenSpeler() {`. If the SpelerFrame windows exists before creating an InschrijvenSpeler frame, you can use something like this instead `new InschrijvenSpeler(spelerFrame);` and change the constructor to `public InschrijvenSpeler(SpelerFrame spelerFrame) {`. That way if the constructor executes, it will actually assign something to `this.spelerFrame`

Comment: That in didn't go well lol. Gave me an infinite look DX. Had to reboot laptop.
In SpelerFrame.java under the button that opens InschrijvenSpeler.java I now have:
`new InschrijvenSpeler(this).setVisible(true);`
And in InschrijvenSpeler.java it now is
`class open
    private InschrijvenSpeler inschrijvenSpeler;
    private SpelerFrame spelerFrame;
    public InschrijvenSpeler(SpelerFrame spelerFrame) {
        initComponents();
        setVisible(true);
        new InschrijvenSpeler(spelerFrame);        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(InschrijvenSpeler.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
    }` character limits :(

Comment: I said that changing the constructor alone would most likely solve the problem. Instead you changed `this.spelerFrame = spelerFrame` to `new InschrijvenSpeler(spelerFrame)` which is indeed a call to itself and will result in an never ending loop. Change it back to `this.spelerFrame = spelerFrame` and report the results here please.

Comment: Oh my bad. Incorrectly read that. Thank you very much. It works now :D!! I would totally upvote the answer but since I'm new to StackOverflow I can't :\

Comment: You can accept this answer as the correct answer, so that other people with similar problems can recognize this as the solution to your problem.